# How would I dynamically insert a textbox that has the same values at all times as a different textbox elsewhere on the page in VB.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, copy

The problem: 
Postback time must not happen. So the generation of the HTML/ASP.net literals are done on Page_Load. Since the user hasn't entered a value for the textboxes that I do calculations on yet, I can't copy those boxes (for a confirmation page) at runtime.

If I was able to make the VB backend do something conceptually like:

```
$("[id$='TEXTBOX1']").change( function() {
$("[id$='TEXTBOX1_COPY']").val( $("[id$='TEXTBOX1']").val()  );
});
```

for each item, but dynamically from the backend, that would be perfect.

Is it possible? 
If I can utilize javascript to do it, that'd be alright too but I'm wondering if there is an easier way than using literals and placeholders to insert textboxes and dynmaically create the code above in javascript on the backend for each element (because the number of elements I'm going to be adding will be unknown - can't hardcode it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
    <input type="text" id="first_source" />
    <input type="text" id="second_source" />
    <input type="text" id="3_source" />
    <hr />
    <input type="text" id="first_copy" />
    <input type="text" id="second_copy" />
    <input type="text" id="3_copy" />
```

and:

```
    $('input[id*="source"]').keyup(function(e)
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
        $('input[id*="'+ id +'_copy"]').val( $(this).val())
    });​
```

I've changed the event from .change to .keyup for a fancier effect :D

http://jsfiddle.net/CqccF/2/

Comment: This is useful. Apparently ajax modalpopoutextender popouts return null on any .val() calls though, so I have to do call those as a seperate function right before it pops up, but that's no biggy! This works, thanks sir!